# read() function not allowing anything to be printed after newline character

Tags: c, linux, printf, newline

I have a function that reads a file from a server and returns the data:

```
int readMessageFromServer(int fileDescriptor) {
  char buffer[MAXMSG];
  int nOfBytes;

  nOfBytes = read(fileDescriptor, buffer, MAXMSG);
  if(nOfBytes < 0) {
    perror("Could not read data from server\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else
    if(nOfBytes == 0) 
      return(-1);
    else 
      printf("Server Message: %s\n",  buffer);
  return(0);
}
```

The problem is with the line

```
printf("Server Message: %s\n",  buffer);
```

If I change this line to

```
printf("Server Message: %s\n>",  buffer);
```

It refuses to print the '>' sign until it gets more data.

Is this a known limitation or am I doing something wrong?

I should probably add that the call to this function looks like this:

```
while(readMessageFromServer(sock) > 0) {continue;};
```

Comment: It is probably printf("Server Message: %s\n>", buffer) with the `>` sign inside the quotes?

Comment: The > is inside the quotes if that's what you mean.

Comment: Corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf` uses stdout which is a buffered output.
Changing `printf` with `fprintf(stderr, ...)` should solve your problem.

Comment: You could also use `fflush(stdout);` or even `fflush(0);` with standard output.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that you probably wanted to write the `>` inside the quotes, you'll need to flush the output buffer by calling `fflush(stdout)`. The buffers are usually only flushed after newlines.

Comment: I don't think `stderr` is buffered.

Answer (score 1):

> nOfBytes = read(fileDescriptor, buffer, MAXMSG);

There is no guarantee how many bytes you read or whether they constitute a null terminated string.  At a minimum you should change to something like this:

```
int readMessageFromServer(int fileDescriptor) {
  char buffer[MAXMSG];
  int nOfBytes;

  nOfBytes = read(fileDescriptor, buffer, MAXMSG - 1);
  if(nOfBytes < 0) {
    perror("Could not read data from server\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else
    if(nOfBytes == 0) 
      return(-1);
    else 
    {
      buffer[nOfBytes] = '\0';
      printf("Server Message: %s\n",  buffer);
      return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the null character tell the read function to stop reading? Where would I put this command?

Comment: No.  You are reading a stream and `read` can return any number of characters up to the number you request.  It puts those bytes into a buffer.  It would be luck if the character in the buffer following the number of bytes you read was a null and therefore created a proper C-string for you to `fprint`.  Note that you *only* need to do this in this case because you are trying to print each read into buffer as a string.